# Diferencia entre public/assets y resources/assets

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando con Laravel y he utilizado la plantilla Stisla, ahora bien necesito agregar algunos plugins de  JS pero no sé dónde guardarlos porque tengo una estructura cómo está.

- **Public**

  - assets

    - css
    - js
  - css
  - js
- **Resources**

  - assets

    - css
    - js
  - css
  - js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la difencia es simple:

**resources/assets** son los archivos que seran compilados como less o sass/ CoffeeScript o typescripts

**public/assets** son los archivos de acceso publico que require tu pagina para funcionar

asi que una vez se compilen los de **resources** se envian a **public**

Comment: Una última duda, y que diferencia tienen con los css y js que están fuera de los assets tanto en public como en resources?

Comment: @kevinrueda Cuáles serían "los que están afuera"? Dónde exactamente?

Comment: @ffflabs si ves public tiene assets/css y también tiene css al igual que resources tiene assets/css y css

Comment: Oh. Eso son estáticos. Tal como están el favicon.ico o el robots.txt, podrías poner un script que no sea producto de una transpilación, por ejemplo el serviceworker de firebase o el de onesignal